# Trying to send Firebase Notification but 0 sent

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send push notifications to my app, but Firebase isn't sending any notifications

expanded notification info
[image]

I am using android studio 3.0, and have connected firebase to the app. I have tried sending a notification to the app when it is at the forefront, and when it is closed.

Will the app being sideloaded affect my ability to send notifications? Please let me know what are common problems that may cause this.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out!

In my build.gradle (module:app), in dependancies:

I had the line:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
```

which was not the most up-to-date version. This is:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
```